# Python 2.7.5 - Run multiple threads simultaneously without slowing down

Tags: python, multithreading, multiplayer

I'm creating a simple multiplayer game in python. I have split the processes up using the default thread module in python. However I noticed that the program still slows down with the speed of other threads. I tried using the multiprocessing module but not all of my objects can be pickled.

Is there an alternative to using the multiprocessing module for running simultaneous processes?

Answer (score 0):

Here are your options:

MPI4PY:
http://code.google.com/p/mpi4py/

Celery:
http://www.celeryproject.org/

Pprocess:
http://www.boddie.org.uk/python/pprocess.html

Parallel Python(PP):
http://www.parallelpython.com/

Answer (score 0):

You need to analyze why your program is slowing down when other threads do their work. Assuming that the threads are doing CPU-intensive work, the slowdown is consistent with threads being serialized by the global interpreter lock.

It is impossible to answer in detaile without knowing more about the nature of the work your threads are performing and of objects that must be shared in parallel. In general, you have two viable options:

1. Use processes, typically through the multiprocessing module. The typical reasons why objects are not picklable is because they contain unpicklable state such as closures, open file handles, or other system resources. But pickle allows objects to implement methods like `__getstate__` or `__reduce__` which identify object's state, using the state to rebuild the objects. If your objects are unpicklable because they are huge, then you might need to write a C extension that stores them in shared memory or a memory-mapped file, and pickle only a key that identifies them in the shared memory.
2. Use threads, finding ways to work around the GIL. If your computation is concentrated in several hot spots, you can move those hot spots to C, and release the GIL for the duration of the computation. For this to work, the computation must not refer to any Python objects, i.e. all data must be extracted from the objects while the GIL is held, and stored back into the Python world after the GIL has been reacquired.